# Textbox restriction error Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If textbox is empty and i press backspace it crashed and highlighted line is

> TB1 = Left(TB1, Len(TB1) - 1)

what can i change to stop that crash

```
Private Sub TB1_Change()
Dim strStrings As String, LastLetter As String
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastLetter = Right(TB1, 1)
strStrings = ","
If InStr(1, strStrings, LastLetter) > 0 Then
    MsgBox LastLetter & " not allowed"
    TB1 = Left(TB1, Len(TB1) - 1)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

It is a textbox where "," is restricted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following sub.

```
Private Sub TB1_Change()
On Error GoTo HarunErrHandler
Dim strStrings As String, LastLetter As String

    If TB1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        LastLetter = Right(TB1, 1)
        strStrings = ","
        If Val(InStr(1, strStrings, LastLetter)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox LastLetter & " not allowed"
            TB1 = Left(TB1, Len(TB1) - 1)
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
HarunErrHandler:
MessageBox = MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `TextBox1` with `TB1` in-case of your `Textbox`.

Comment: still getting same error INVALID PROCEDURE CALL or Argument RUN TIME error 5 and same line is highlight

Comment: But I tested and its working. Can you share a sample workbook, so that we can check in real time.

Comment: here is link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_kP5vLX56wJb3R1TlowSy0tV00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: just write ABC, it will give you msg click ok use backspace and it will crash

Comment: I just test your file. Its working fine. I am able to type without any message. When I type `Comma (,)` then it prompt message. May problem your excel any other setting. Can you test the file in another pc. I found your file completely working.

Comment: Have you type "ABCCCC," after getting error click OK after that use backspace to delete all you will get again msg not allowed on click ok and backspace it will crash i tried in 3 PC

Comment: Got your point. Se my edited answer. You need to use a `if...` condition to handle blank. I also suggest to use a `Error Handler`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103055/discussion-between-harun24hr-and-muhammad-khurrum-butt).